# how to run UNIONALL query in BIGQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm encountering following error while running `UNIONALL` query in Bigquery compose query console(web-UI).

`Encountered " <ID> "UNIONALL "" at line 23, column 10. Was expecting: <EOF>`

All I'm running the following query

```
SELECT 2 AS y 
UNIONALL
SELECT 1 AS y;
```

How can I manage to run this above query..

I have checked and unchecked `Use Legacy SQL` checkbox multiple times but no gain here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `UNION ALL` (notice the space). Your query should be:

```
SELECT 2 AS y 
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS y;
```

You need to use standard SQL.